# Using higher order component in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, i18next, higher-order-components, react-i18next

I am trying to use react-i18next with Typescript, and I am running into a few issues.

Here's my interface for the props that I am expecting.

```
import * as i18n from 'i18next';

export interface ReactI18nProps {
  t: i18n.TFunction;
}
```

I then have a navigation component, which I compose.

```
import { translate } from 'react-i18next';

function Navigation({ t }: ReactI18nProps) {
  const userProfile = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile') || '');
  return (
    ...
  );
}

export default translate('navigation')(Navigation);
```

And now I simply want to render this component that I have composed

```
function Appliances({ location }: NavLinkProps) {
  const userId = location && location.state.userId;
  return (
    <div>
      <Navigation />
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, at this juncture, TS fails me and I get the following error

```
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ReactI18nProps'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactI18nProps'.
    Property 't' is missing in type '{}'.
```

Could someone please explain what I am doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message suggests:

> Property 't' is missing in type '{}'

Your component expects the props to be:

```
interface ReactI18nProps {
    t: i18n.TFunction;
}
```

But you're not passing this `t`:

```
<Navigation />
```

You can either make this `t` property optional:

```
interface ReactI18nProps {
    t?: i18n.TFunction;
}
```

Or satisfy it:

```
<Navigation t={ (key: string, options: i18n.TOptions) => return getTranslation(key, options) } />
```

---

#### Edit

Based on the type definitions for `react-i18next` [translation function](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-i18next/src/translate.d.ts#L15):

```
function translate<TKey extends string = string>
    (namespaces?: TKey[] | TKey, options?: TOptions)
        : <C extends Function>(WrappedComponent: C) => C;
```

The type of the component you pass is the exact type you get back, meaning that the same props type is used.
In this case, you'll need to use an optional `t` because sometimes it is used without this property (when you call it) but then it is used with `t` (when the `translate` method calls it).

To avoid the compiler complaining about `t` possibly be undefined you can use the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator):

```
function Navigation({ t }: ReactI18nProps) {
    ...
    const translation = t!(...);
    ...
}
```

Notice that it's using `t!` instead of just `t`.

Comment: I don't want to pass `t` because it is coming from the composing component, and if I declare the property type to be optional typescript complains that the object can possibly be undefined (in which case I will have to verify that it is defined). 

Is there a better solution to this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. If you need `t` then pass it, if you don't need it then remove it from the props and/or the `Navigation` args.

Comment: From my understanding, `t` is coming from the HOC `translate`, so I should not have to pass it explicitly.

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: Thanks, the non-null assertion operator is exactly what I was looking for! :)